# Замена подстроки массив символов

Tags: c++

Мне надо создать динамический класс для символов, для этого мне надо сделать такую операцию как замена подстроки на другую подстроку.

Подскажите, как это сделать.

Comment: Если заменяющая подстрока длиннее, то выделить дополнительную память, сдвинуть вправо хвост, если короче, то сдвинуть хвост влево, затем просто скопировать символы подстроки в нужное место.

Comment: А можете показать  на примере пожалуйста , я просто не понимаю

Comment: Вы свои структуры данных в тексте вопроса напишите